# Play / Run captured HTTP traffic from file

Tags: parsing, http, dataset

I have a raw HTTP traffic file with following format :

```
---------------------- dataset.txt ----------------------------------

GET http://localhost:8080/tienda1/index.jsp HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.8 (like Gecko)
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: x-gzip, x-deflate, gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: utf-8, utf-8;q=0.5, *;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en
Host: localhost:8080
Cookie: JSESSIONID=1F767F17239C9B670A39E9B10C3825F4
Connection: close

POST http://localhost:8080/tienda1/publico/anadir.jsp HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.8 (like Gecko)
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: x-gzip, x-deflate, gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: utf-8, utf-8;q=0.5, *;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en
Host: localhost:8080
Cookie: JSESSIONID=933185092E0B668B90676E0A2B0767AF
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close
Content-Length: 68

id=3&nombre=Vino+Rioja&precio=100&cantidad=55&B1=A%F1adir+al+carrito

...
...
```

---

Is there any utility to read this file and submit to my local web server?

Answer (score 0):

You have two requests here.
First is GET, second is POST.

Provided that you are having such format as above, you could write simple program that will ( in order)

1. Divide the sheet into separate HTTP requests
2. Parse requests and divide them into variables like : type of request (GET or POST), User-Agent and "headers" in general, request DATA, request submit URL
3. Create and maintain session with specific server (cookies etc)
4. Iterate through the loop and submit the data

It would be perfect to solve the problem in [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Parsing may be done in python basic lib.